# Is there a way to set a win32 control hwnd so that it can't be resized or moved?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, hwnd

I just want the win32 control to ignore all moving and resizing operations. Is this possible?

Basically I am hosting an old win32 control inside a Winforms app but the main application is resizing and moving this control when using certain commands. I want the window to ignore these basically or become immune to these operations.

Comment: Subclass and move yourself back on any WM_SIZE events?

Comment: How is the control being resized? With appropriate [anchoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx), I wouldn't expect the child control to be resized.

Comment: Alexei has your solution. Subclass the control (whether you own its code or not, you're creating it in your application and therefore functionally own it), handle the appropriate messages, and eat them. Have you tried this? What part didn't work?

Comment: @CodyGray: Thanks guys. It's a C++ app with .net support so I wrote a .net app that I launch from within the app that have access to the app using its .net API. I just set the win32 control's parent to my Winform. Can I still subclass it? Because I am not creating this control from scratch, it's already there. Also the other functions in this app, explicitly move and resize this control which is why I wanted to stop it. Not sure how I can subclass this control? I only have its hwnd handle, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I understand the rationale behind your current design, as discussed in the comments. Since you appear to own all of the code, why not either (A) combine it so that the project creating the control is also the one responsible for managing it, or (B) change it so that you aren't moving/resizing the control when you clearly don't want to. But I trust that you have a reason for doing it the way you are, and I don't really have enough information to insist any more strongly.

> Can I still subclass it? Because I am not creating this control from scratch, it's already there.

Yes, technically you can subclass *any* control, but you shouldn't unless you own it. Of course, that doesn't mean that you own the code for the control, it only means that you have ownership of the created object. I realize that's confusing, but I can't think of any better way to explain it in words.

So how about an example. Windows comes with a whole bunch of common controls that applications are encouraged to use. Your application doesn't own the code for any of those controls—it resides in DLLs that come with Windows. But because you are the one creating and using those controls, you have every right to subclass them to modify their behavior.

> Not sure how I can subclass this control? I only have its hwnd handle, that's it.

The two standard approaches to subclassing a control, given its handle, in Win32 are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183.aspx). Either one of those approaches would be a good bet.

Basically, you're just replacing the existing window procedure with your custom window procedure. That will get called first, allowing you to do whatever you want. You can either eat the message, or pass it on to the next window procedure in the chain. This may or may not be the default window procedure, depending on whether the window was subclassed previously, but that really doesn't matter to you.

Of course, you'll need to write a fair amount of P/Invoke code to make this work. Check [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/) for help (but don't blindly rely on their declarations, I've seen plenty that are incorrect).

Do be sure that you unsubclass *before* destroying the window. A common mistake is forgetting to clean up after yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I am using this application: http://area.autodesk.com/img/products/maya/nondestructive_live_retargeting.png So as you can see I don't own or have the source code other than it's API but it also has a .net wrapper. In the .net wrapper, I also don't have access to its controls like that dialog. You are not able to create that window. There is a function to get the handle of that which I am using to change its parent from the main app to my winforms. But my winforms is still running under the main app. When I change it, then the control moves into my window, which is what I want.

Comment: Except when that happens, the main app still send that dialog/window certain messages to move and resize it so I am trying to remove those. Another user said to use another message but I didn't work on this since then.